# How to debug a timer

Tags: stm32

Im having problem setting up the TIM1 in "External Source Mode 1". Im writing to CH1 programmatically but nothing comes out of the timer no matter what settings I try. Is there a way to debug a timer, meaning checking the values at every stage, for example values of TI2FP1, IC1, and then IC1PS. I cant find them while debugging 
Edit: If you're familiar these are not the names of the ordinary config registers. Those I know how to find.

Comment: Which particular STM32 microcontroller are you using? Are you using STM32Cube for code generation? Are you using the HAL or LL drivers?

Comment: F411re. All bare bone registers fun. Cmsis. No libraries. Evening I'll post the code

Comment: Kudos. That's brave!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IC1F` and `IC1PS` configuration bits you refer to are found within the TIM1 `CCMR1` register. In Truestudio - in the debug perspective, in the SFRs tab - expand `TIM1` and then `CCMR1_Input`. See picture. (That screenshot is for an STM32F302RC, but I believe the TIM1 registers are very similar - if not almost identical - for the STM32F411RE).

[image]

`TI2FP1`, on the other hand, is a *signal* - not a configuration bit stored in the microcontroller's memory.

If you are using global variables inside the timer ISRs, don't forget to declare them `volatile`. Otherwise they may not be updating as you expect (at least once you enable optimization).

Comment: Firt part I know, the signal part I was suspecting. That is what i meant, if you can read this signals;) But I guess not. Thanks. No rep, no vote;)